# Does my rigorous definiiton make sense and give what I want? How do we simplify my definiton?

Tags: measure-theory, definition, outer-measure

My previous measure in this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4168201/has-research-involving-the-generalization-of-the-arithmetic-mean-been-done-for-t) doesn't make sense so I made modifications. I need someone to check whether my definitions improved.

Suppose we have the following definition?

### Definition

- $\ell$ is the length of an interval
- $\left(J_{k} \right)_{k=1}^{m}$, for $m\in\mathbb{N}$, are a sequence of **open** intervals where $\;\ell(J_1)=...=\ell(J_m)=g\in\mathbb{R}^{+}$ and the infimum is taken over all possible $J_k$

\begin{align}
\mathcal{M}(g,S)=g\cdot\inf\left\{m\in\mathbb{N}: {S^{\prime}\text{ is countable}, \; \left(S\setminus S^{\prime}\right)\subseteq\bigcup\limits_{k=1}^{m}J_{k}}\right\}
\end{align}

and

$$\mathcal{N}(S,A)=\lim\limits_{g\to 0}\frac{\mathcal{M}\left(g,S\right)}{\mathcal{M}\left(g,A\right)}$$

then if

\begin{align}
& \mathcal{O}(g,S)=\\ & \begin{cases} \small{g\cdot\inf\left\{m\in\mathbb{N}: {S_{j}\subseteq S, \;  \mathcal{N}(S_{j},A)=0,\;\bigcup\limits_{j=1}^{\infty}{S}_{j}=S^{\prime\prime},\;\left(S\setminus S^{\prime\prime}\right)\subseteq\bigcup\limits_{k=1}^{m}J_{k}}\right\}} & A \text{ is uncountable}\\
g\cdot\inf\left\{m\in\mathbb{N}: {S\subseteq\bigcup\limits_{k=1}^{m}J_{k}}\right\} & A \text{ is countable}
\end{cases}
\end{align}

then the outer measure is

$$\mathcal{P}^{*}(S,A)=\lim\limits_{g\to 0}\frac{\mathcal{O}(g,S)}{\mathcal{O}(g,A)}$$

And the inner measure is $\mathcal{P}_{*}(S,A)=1-\mathcal{P}^{*}(A\setminus S,A)$, meaning measure $\mathcal{P}(S,A)$ exists when $\mathcal{P}^{*}(S,A)=\mathcal{P}_{*}(S,A)$.

While reading note:

1. *Does my definition make sense*
2. *Does it give the same value as the Lebesgue Measure when $A=\mathbb{R}$ and $S\subseteq A$?*
3. *Does it give what else I wish for? (See Intuitive explanation and Example)*
4. *How can we simplify it? (See the Example)*

### Intuitive Explanation

I wish to define an outer measure $\mathcal{P}^{*}$ where $m=m_1$ intervals cover $S$ and $m=m_2$ intervals cover $A$. Note all the intervals that cover $S$ and $A$ must have the same length.

To solve $\mathcal{P}^{*}$, if $S$ and $A$ are uncountable, find $S^{\prime}\subseteq S$ and $A^{\prime}\subseteq A$ that can be covered by points or already proven to be "infinitesmially small" such when covering $S\setminus S^{\prime}$ and $A\setminus{A^{\prime}}$ use box-counting dimensions to find total length of minimum $m_1$ intervals of $g$-length covering $S$ divided by total length of minimum $m_2$ intervals $g$ length covering $A$ (then find the infimum of the result). Note to get the total lengths from the minimum $m_1$ and $m_2$ intervals, they must be written as function of $g$ or $m_1(g)$ and $m_2(g)$ and each of must be multiplied by $g$ as $g\to 0$. Make sure you choose a $S^{\prime}$ and $A^{\prime}$ where we get the infimum bound of $\lim\limits_{g\to 0}\left(g \cdot m_1(g)\right)/\left({g \cdot m_2(g)}\right)$.

In my definitons, note $g \cdot n(g)$ becomes $\mathcal{M}(g,S)$ and $g \cdot m(g)$ becomes $\mathcal{M}(g,A)$.

### Example

Suppose we define $A=\mathcal{G}\cup\mathcal{C}\cup\left(\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1]\right)$ and $S=\mathcal{G}\cup\mathbb{Q}$ where $\mathcal{C}$ is the cantor set and  $$G_{0}=[0,1]$$

$$G_{n+1}=\frac{G_{n}}{5}\cup\frac{G_{n}+2}{5}\cup\frac{G_{n}+4}{5}$$

$$\mathcal{G}=\bigcap\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}G_n$$

To solve a measure say $\mathcal{P}(S,A)$, I wish to cover $\mathbb{Q}$ with countably infinite points and cover remaining points of $S$, being $\mathcal{G}$, and remaining points of $A$, being $\mathcal{G}\cup\mathcal{C}$, with intervals of same length.

Now suppose all intervals have the length $g$. For every $g\in\mathbb{R}^{+}$, take the total length of all the intervals covering $\mathcal{G}$ as approximately

$$g \cdot 3^{\ln(1/g)/\ln(5)}$$

And we get the total length of the intervals covering $\mathcal{G}\cup\mathcal{C}$ as approximately

$$g\cdot 3^{\ln(1/g)/\ln(5)}+g\cdot 2^{\ln(1/g)/\ln(3)}$$

Then our outer measure should be the infimum of

$$\frac{g \cdot 3^{\ln(1/g)/\ln(5)}}{g \cdot 3^{\ln(1/g)/\ln(5)}+g\cdot 2^{\ln(1/g)/\ln(3)}}$$

Which is

$$\lim\limits_{g\to 0}\frac{g \cdot 3^{\ln(1/g)/\ln(5)}}{g \cdot 3^{\ln(1/g)/\ln(5)}+g\cdot 2^{\ln(1/g)/\ln(3)}}$$

I calculated the limit is $1$.

Comment: "closed zero length intervals", meaning points?

Comment: @CalvinKhor Yes

Comment: Well my 2¢ would be to tell you to call a point a point. But I can't make it to the end of the paragraph, so what do I know

Comment: @CalvinKhor If you comeback be sure to see my new definition.

Comment: I am not sure if it is ok to make so many edits.

Comment: @supinf Should I have made a new post?

Comment: @JoseAvilez I'm not sure where else to go to get answers. The people at Varsity Tutors aren't knowledgeable enough and PHD students and Professor don't have the time and patience. I will type one more question and that should be it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Edit since the bounty notice says "Current answers are outdated") The question is now on revision [15](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/4173052/15). The answer below was meant to respond to revision [7](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/4173052/7) which was written about 24 hours ago, and had the following definition:

> ### Definition
>
> If $S\subseteq A$:
>
> - $\ell$ is the length of an interval
> - $\left(I_{j}\right)_{j=1}^{\infty}$ and $\left(J_{k} \right)_{k=1}^{m}$ for $m\in\mathbb{N}\cup\{\infty\}$, are a sequence of **closed** intervals where $\ell(I_1)=...=\ell(I_n)=0$,  $\;\ell(J_1)=...=\ell(J_m)=g\in\mathbb{R}^{+}$ and the infimum in the equation below is taken over $m$
>
> \begin{align}
> & \mathcal{M}(g,S,\left(I_j\right)_{j=1}^{n},\left(J_k\right)_{k=1}^{m})=\\ &\begin{cases} \inf\limits_{m\in\mathbb{N}\cup\{\infty\}}\left\{gm: S\subseteq\left(\bigcup\limits_{k=1}^{m}J_{k}\right)\cup\left(\bigcup\limits_{j=1}^{\infty}I_{j}\right)\right\} & A \text{ is uncountable}\\
> \inf\limits_{m\in\mathbb{N}\cup\{\infty\}}\left\{gm: S\subseteq\left(\bigcup\limits_{k=1}^{m}J_{k}\right)\right\} & A \text{ is countable}
> \end{cases}
> \end{align}
>
> Then the outer-measure is
>
> $$\mathcal{P}^{*}(S,A)=\lim\limits_{g\to 0}\frac{\mathcal{M}\left(g,S,\left(I_j\right)_{j=1}^{n},\left(J_k\right)_{k=1}^{m}\right)}{\mathcal{M}\left(g,A,\left(I_j\right)_{j=1}^{n},\left(J_k\right)_{k=1}^{m}\right)}$$
>
> And the inner measure is $\mathcal{P}_{*}(S,A)=1-\mathcal{P}^{*}(A\setminus S,A)$, meaning measure $\mathcal{P}(S,A)

As far as I can tell from a quick scan of the current version of the question, some minor details were changed (e.g. closed is now open, the $I_k$s have disappeared), but you have now introduced two new intermediate objects $\mathcal{N,O}$. Regardless, it seems the second and third bullet points below still apply.

---

Let me attempt to follow your definition. I'll try to compute with $S=[0,1]=A=[0,1]$. It looks like you have placed absolutely no restrictions on

- the sets consisting of one point, $I_j$. So let me set them all to be $\{0\}$.
- the number of intervals $J_k$, denoted $m$. So I will pick $m=1$.
- the intervals, $J_k$, except for their length. Since $m=1$, I only need to decide what $J_1$ is, so let me choose $J_1=[0,g]$.
- the number of points $I_j$ that are used to define $\mathcal M$, $n$. So I will pick $n=1$....but $n$ only appears on the LHS; on the RHS, you still use $\cup_{j=1}^\infty I_j$, so perhaps $n=\infty$ is chosen for me.

Now I reach the definition of $\mathcal M$. Unfortunately, you are now taking an infimum over the quantity $m$ that I already fixed to be $m=1$. So I guess I should release the definition of $m$ and allow $m$ to vary. Then I need to define what $J_k$ are for $k\ge1$. Let me set them all to be $[0,g]$. Then I compute for $g<1$,
$$\mathcal M(g, [0,1],(I_j)_j, (J_k)_k)=\inf_m\{ mg : [0,1]\subset [0,g]\cup\{0\}\} = \inf \emptyset = \infty$$

Now I have an issue and cannot continue, as $\mathcal P^*$ involves $\infty/\infty$.

---

I highly doubt this is what you wanted. Perhaps, it should be something like

$$\mathcal M(g,S) = g\inf\left\{m\in\mathbb N:\substack{\displaystyle \text{there exists a cover of $S$ by $m$ closed intervals of length $g$,}\ \\\displaystyle \text{up to a countable set} } \right\}$$
or more precisely, if you are uncomfortable with "up to a countable set",
$$\mathcal M(g,S) = g\inf\left\{m \in\mathbb N:\substack{\displaystyle \text{there exists  $m$ closed intervals $(J_i)_{i=1}^m$ of length $g$,  }\ \\\displaystyle \text{such that $S\setminus \left(\bigcup_i J_i\right)$ is at most countable} }  \right\}$$
With this, $\mathcal M(g,[0,1])=1$ whenever $g=1/k$ for some $k\in\mathbb N$, and as $g\to 0$ $\mathcal M(g,[0,1])\to 1$. Also, I'm no expert, but what I wrote is quite close to the thing you define with lengths at most $\delta$ before you define a Hausdorff measure...

Comment: Does $\lim\limits_{g\to0}\mathcal{M}(g,S)/\mathcal{M}(g,A)$ equal the Lebesgue Measure when $A=\mathbb{R}$? It seems I am only disclosing countable sets but when $A=\mathbb{R}$ I must have countable additivity to disclude sets measure zero with respect to $\mathcal{P}^{*}(S,A)$.

Comment: I made edits so that it all meets the Lebesgue Measure when $A=\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I don't have the time or willpower at the moment to understand why there are two new objects $\mathcal{N,O}$, so I have merely edited my answer so that it can be read without going to the revision history of your question

Comment: You don't have to help further I added $\mathcal{N}$ and $\mathcal{O}$ so we get the Lebesgue Measure when $A=\mathbb{R}$

Comment: If $A=\mathbb R$ then you are dividing by infinity in the definition of $\mathcal N$. Also I would suggest you refrain from only using symbols in your formula of words make it easier. Indeed you are forced to use words when you have to write **outside** the definition that the infimum is over all possible collections $J_k$

Comment: ...consequently either $\mathcal N$ is not defined or it is equal to zero, so you have a large collection of sets with $\mathcal N$ equal zero. e.g. $\mathcal N([0,1],\mathbb R) = 0$

Comment: Thanks for coming back. 

Suppose $A$ equals an interval with finite length say $[0,1]$. And $S=[0,1/2]$. Do we end up with $\mathcal{N}(S,A)=1/2$? Do we also get $\mathcal{O}(S,A)=1/2$?

Comment: Yes for the first; possible for the second, but that would require me being sure of the meaning of $\mathcal N=0$, which I can't spend time to check atm. At this point, instead of constantly updating your definition, my opinion is that it might be better for you to properly learn/internalise the notion of a Hausdorff measure (and measures in general); their definitions are the result of plenty of blood, sweat and tears, of the sort it is taking you to refine your definition. After which you can revisit this construction. The book by Evans and Gariepy has lots of details

Comment: I plan on taking measure theory courses to strengthen my definition. I believe the final draft is decent but needs more rigor. It should give the Lebesgue Measure of S divided by the Lebesgue Measure of A when A is a finite length interval.